# How to hide some slides from presentation?

Tags: hyperref

I have some slides, which are not part of the main presentation, but I want to shown them if the audience asks some questions. The problem is, that how can I hide these slides?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please show us what you have so far and add a minimal working example  [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (including only relevant packages). So that the people here don't need to start from scratch.

Comment: I would recommend you to put them into the appendix and to create links to them. So if you show a main formula on the slide and someone asks for some explanation you just click the link and are taken directly to the appendix-slide. If you create a link back you can easily get back to where you came from.

Comment: Are you using `beamer`, or something else to create the presentation. As Uwe says, just move the slides to the end of the presentation, that's probably the easiest.

Answer (score 6):

The following should do the trick however the first link does not seem to work and I have no clue why. Have a look at the `hyperref` manual, `hypertarget` also seems a good candidate.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=red,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=red}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some formula}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2\label{linkback}
\end{equation}

See \hyperref[moreexplanation]{Appendix} for details

\end{frame}


\section{Appendix}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Appendix}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2\label{moreexplanation}
\end{equation}

This is a very important formula. It made Math great again! 

\hyperref[linkback]{Link}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also will put the extra slides at the end, so simply hitting the space bar or so you can show your short presentation without interference.  You can use `appendixnumberbeamer` package to reset the frame number counter when start the supplementary material. Change a bit the frame style  would help also to check quickly in which part you are at any moment.

At strategic points, I will put some buttoms using `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` as Uwe suggest to go and back, but using Beamer's buttons to make more distinguishable from slide text (it should be easy to click but also  easy to ignore when you have little time).

The subsections 11.1 of the manual (Adding Hyperlinks and Buttons, page 104) show some others interesting options as `\hyperlinkslideprev`, etc. Check it.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\geometry{paperheight=1.5in,paperwidth=3.5in}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer} 
\begin{document}
% Main presentation
\begin{frame}{One}{Short presentation}
\hypertarget{BEGIN} The begining \hfill 
\hyperlink{LONG}{\beamergotobutton{Verbose mode}} \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Four}{Short presentation}\hypertarget{END} The end \end{frame}
\appendix 
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=olive}
% Extra material
\begin{frame}{Two}{Extra slide I} \hypertarget{LONG}  More stuff \hfill 
\hyperlink{END}{\beamergotobutton{Return}}\end{frame}
% More extra material
\begin{frame}{Three}{Extra slide II}    And munch more \hfill   
\hyperlink{END}{\beamergotobutton{Next}}    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note also that the next subsection (11.2 Repeating a Frame at a Later Point) could be also of interest for this question.